# Lottie iOS animation is not working in mobile

Tags: ios, swift

We’ve tried to implement Lottie animation in iOS app. we added a json file which works fine in android and web but not in iOS i.e., title is invisible and extra lines are appeared on background. here’s code snippet used to play Lottie animation:

```
animationView = .init(name: "experts") // json file name
animationView?.frame = view.bounds
animationView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
animationView?.loopMode = .playOnce
animationView?.animationSpeed = 0.5
view.addSubview(animationView!)
animationView?.play { (finished) in
    // animation is finished
}
```

Lottie iOS version - 3.3.0
Xcode version - 12.4
iOS version - 12.5/15.3

Comment: could you share the current animation and the expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it's working fine:-

```
animationView.animation = Animation.named("74683-delivery") //JSON file name
animationView.center = view.center
animationView.frame = view.bounds
animationView.backgroundColor = .white
animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
animationView.loopMode = .playOnce
animationView.play()
view.addSubview(animationView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code !! I tried your solution its not working as expected.

Comment: Can you please provide your JSON file and a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: title is invisible in the app. when this json file is loaded.